# Eclipse remote system explorer terminal with weird characters

Tags: eclipse, ssh, terminal, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse remote system explorer to connect to remote servers, the terminal keep displaying weird characters, and duplicate whatever i write.

[image]

any idea about how to solve this issue or how can i use the TM Terminal with  the remote system explorer?